# Google maps timeline queries

Tags: google-maps

I know I can use Google maps timeline to see where I have been at some point in time. Is it also possible to have more sophisticated queries, like when was the last time I visited some place?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy solution but you can [export the KML file](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/v8iaQF_Y0fw) and if you know the coordinates of the place (obtainable in maps/timeline) you can run a search on the KML file using a text editor that can handle a large file easily (notepad++) or a script (Python might be easy here).

The JSON file might be easier to handle but I don't know much about JSON.